# In a table-cell, how to set the background color and put content in the middle?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The next image is currently what I have.

[image]

And this is what should be:

[image]

As you can see, the dots on the third column are not aligned. It should meet the next requirement:

[image]

As you can imagine, I might use two divs because of the two borders.

This next code is what I have tried all day long, I cannot achieve to position the dots in the middle with the background-color stretched (considering the two border colors). What am I wrong? Should I remove everything and change it by a flexbox? I'll appreciate your help.

**Html code:**

```
You have 4 items in your cart

<article class="cart-item">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="images/item1.jpg"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <h4 class="title">Dexter Men's Max Bowling Shoes (Right Handed Only)</h4>
        <span class="description">Shipping 3-day with UPS</span>
        <span class="description">Color: Gray</span>
        <span class="description">Size: 28.5</span>
        <span class="price">$60.00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="grouped-dots">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**Css code**

```
.cart-item
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cart-item>div
{
    display: table-cell;
}
.left,.center
{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.left
{
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 33.33%;
}
.left img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.center
{
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
}
.right
{
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
}
.right .grouped-dots
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
.cart-item .grouped-dots span::after
{
    color: #CCCCCC;
    content: '.';
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

This approach is using table and table-cells as display values. If you think I'm in the wrong path, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Is it just adding background color to the column? http://jsfiddle.net/cpyzcujk/

Comment: Hmmm... just noticed that my demo above works in FF but not Chrome. All I did was add the background color to `.right`.

Comment: @Michael_B exactly, that's what I'm looking for in chrome now. I supposed it is because of the table displays values, but not really!

Comment: A simple flexbox in `.grouped-dots` does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/cpyzcujk/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this style:

```
.right .grouped-dots {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Since its as tall as its parent, there's no room for it to move vertically to the "middle."

Remove that style, and move its background color to `.right`:

```
.right {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xvrhsayn/1)